# Tinkerpop3 custom edge id generator

Tags: java, tinkerpop3, tinkergraph

I use `TinkerGraph` for integration tests (extended unit tests) in Java. In this implementation `Edge ids` are generated as a sequence of Integers. I want to change that so they are generated as random UUIDs. The reason for this is to get my test setup behave closer to my production graph database. Can I do this in `Tinkerpop3` and if so how?

I have found that in Tinkerpop/blueprints (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/id-implementation) there existed an `IdGraph.IdFactory` which seemingly would provide what I need. However as I understand it that is not available for Tinkerpop3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be possible but will require some work. `Vertex` and `Edge Ids` in `TinkerGraph` are determined using `IDManagers` which is done [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/tinkergraph-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.java#L523).

You can see that this is decided via a config value which ends up using reflection to construct the `IDManager`.

So you would have to do the following:

1. Create your own `IDManager` by implementing the [interface](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/tinkergraph-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.java#L545) you can use the [default manager](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/tinkergraph-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.java#L565) as a guideline. For example:

   ```
   public enum DefaultIdManager implements IdManager {
       ...
       ANY {
           @Override
           public Long getNextId(final TinkerGraph graph) {
               return unique random number
           }
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You would then have to create a config with your new manager specified and create the tinkergraph using that manager:

   ```
   BaseConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();
   config.addProperty(TinkerGraph.GREMLIN_TINKERGRAPH_EDGE_ID_MANAGER, "your.package.structure.YourIdManager.ANY");
   TinkerGraph.open(config);
   ```

I would love to know if there is an easier way but I think this will work.

**Side Note:**

It might be easier to check if your production graph DB provides an in-memory layer. I know a few graph dbs do and using that rather than `TinkerGraph` will likely be better. `TinkerGraph` is really only meant for plating around I believe.